# How can I add flowbite to the React.Js . Followed the guide on the flowbite but components doesn't working well

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

Hello I used flowbite along with tailwindcss and react js But the components are not working in the react

## (You can click the links to see the directory Images)

[I imported the flowbite in the index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KemAx.png)

[Created a components called Drp stands for dropdown and add a dropdown from the flowbite components section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjtrr.png)

[This Drp component you can see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWkqL.png)

Then this is my tailwind.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"],
theme: {
extend: {},
 },
plugins: [
require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
}
```

but this is not working ,How to fix this???

Comment: here is a temporary  work-around https://stackoverflow.com/a/72160480/12098866

Answer (score 4):

Follow these points in "index.js" file:

Replace:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'; => import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

User render method like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image]